# Object function behaves differently inside and outside of constructor?

Tags: c++, function, constructor

I have this `MapReduceJob.hpp` file to initialize a map/reduce job (I'm developing a parallel mapreduce skeleton project).

```
#ifndef MAPREDUCEJOB_HPP_
#define MAPREDUCEJOB_HPP_

#include <ff/farm.hpp>
#include "TaskScheduler.hpp"
#include "MapReduceWorker.hpp"
#include "MapResult.hpp"
#include "TextInputFormat.hpp"
#include "LineRecordReader.hpp"
#include "MapReduceJob.hpp"
#include "TaskScheduler.hpp"

using namespace ff;

/*
 * MIK: map input key
 * MIV: map input value
 * MOK: map output key
 * MOV: map output value
 * RK: reduce output key
 * RV: reduce output value
 */


template<typename MIK, typename MIV, typename MOK, typename MOV, typename RK, typename RV>
class MapReduceJob {
public:
    MapReduceJob(   string file_name,
                    function<void(MIK key, MIV value, MapResult<MIK,MIV,MOK,MOV>*)> map_func ,
                    function<pair<RK,RV> (MOK key, vector<MOV> list_value)> red_func,
                    int nWorkers){
        farm = new ff_Farm<> ( [nWorkers]() {
          std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ff_node> > Workers;
            for(int i=0;i<nWorkers;++i)
                Workers.push_back(std::unique_ptr<ff_node_t<Task<int,string,string,int>,Result<int,string,string,int>> >(new MapReduceWorker<int,string,string,int>()));
          return Workers;
        }() );
        MapScheduler<int,string,string,int> e(farm->getlb(),file_name,nWorkers,map_func);
        farm->remove_collector(); // removes the default collector
        farm->add_emitter(e);
        farm->wrap_around();
        if (farm->run_and_wait_end()<0) error("running myFarm");
    }
    MapReduceJob(   string file_name,
                    function<void(MIK key, MIV value, MapResult<MIK,MIV,MOK,MOV>*)> map_func ,
                    function<pair<RK,RV> (MOK key, vector<MOV> list_value)> red_func)
        : MapReduceJob (file_name, map_func, red_func, ff_realNumCores()){}
    void waitForCompletion(){
        if (farm->run_and_wait_end()<0) error("running myFarm");
    }
private:
    ff_Farm<> *farm;
};

#endif /* MAPREDUCEJOB_HPP_ */
```

I know that you could not know [FastFlow](http://calvados.di.unipi.it/), but how is it possible that the first call of `farm->run_and_wait_end()` is correct and the second one do *nothing*? This happens also if I remove one of the two calls (the first one still behaves correctly, the second one does nothing).

I run/test the code above with this `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <ff/pipeline.hpp> // defines ff_pipeline and ff_Pipe
#include <ff/farm.hpp>

#include "MapReduceJob.hpp"

using namespace ff;

int main() {
    std::function<void(int key, string value,MapResult<int,string,string,int> *result)> map_func = [](int key,string value,MapResult<int,string,string,int> *result) {
        istringstream iss(value);
        vector<string> tokens{istream_iterator<string>{iss},istream_iterator<string>{}};
        for(string key : tokens)
            result->emit(key,1);
    };
    std::function<pair<string,int> (string key, vector<int> list_value)> red_func = [](string key, vector<int> list_value){
        pair<string,int> result(key,list_value.size());
        return result;
    };
    MapReduceJob<int,string,string,int,string,int> job ("file",map_func,red_func,4);
    job.waitForCompletion();
    return 0;
}
```

The crucial instruction are the declaration of `job` and `job.waitFroCompletion();` (which doesn't produce anything).

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to test this class?

Comment: What about adding a second call to farm->run_and_wait_end() in the constructor and see if that executes as you expect?

Comment: Yes it does! Don't know